# cannot borrow `reader` as mutable more than once at a time

Tags: rust

**Full error:**

```
  --> src\readers.rs:10:30
   |
5  | pub fn get_sequences(raw_sequences: &str) -> Result<Vec<Cow<[u8]>>, Error> {
   |                                     - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
10 |     while let Some(result) = reader.next() {
   |                              ^^^^^^ `reader` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
...
15 |     Ok(sequences)
   |     ------------- returning this value requires that `reader` is borrowed for `'1`
```

**Code:**

```
pub fn get_sequences(raw_sequences: &str) -> Result<Vec<Cow<[u8]>>, Error> {
    let bytes = raw_sequences.as_bytes();
    let mut reader = Reader::new(BufReader::new(bytes));
    let mut sequences: Vec<Cow<[u8]>> = vec![];

    while let Some(result) = reader.next() {
        let record = result?;
        sequences.push(record.full_seq());
    }

    Ok(sequences)
}
```

I'm using the SeqIO crate (https://github.com/markschl/seq_io/tree/v0.3)

Honestly not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `full_seq()` doesn't copy the data, it just stores a reference to the reader's buffer, which could become invalid the next time you call `reader.next()`, so the compiler won't let you call `reader.next()` while that reference still exists. Maybe try using `owned_seq()` instead? That should make an owned copy of the data to store in `sequences` so that the reader can reuse/overwrite the buffer when you call `reader.next()`.

Answer (score 0):

the fix is change full_seq to owned_seq, and return Vec<Vec> instead of Vec<Cow<[u8]>>, the is because `record` do have a reference to reader, and full_seq return a Cow type that has implicit reference to record, thus it has reference to the reader which is a local variable

```
pub fn get_sequences(raw_sequences: &str) -> Result<Vec<Vec<u8>>, Error> {
    let bytes = raw_sequences.as_bytes();
    let mut reader = Reader::new(bytes);
    let mut sequences = vec![];

    while let Some(result) = reader.next() {
        let record = result?;
        sequences.push(record.owned_seq());
    }

    Ok(sequences)
}
```